# Force test on extension of abstract class

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have an abstract class that has good test coverage.  I want to make sure that any extensions of that class also pass the tests of the abstract class.  Is there any way to ensure this with code using JUnit?

Comment: Would it be possible to add an example to your question?

Comment: I can under stand your pain, but there is freedom given to sub-classes creators not other way. I don't know think there is a way.

Comment: for an example: if classB overrides a method of classA I want to make sure testClassAMethod still passes for classB or force classB to also override testClassAMethod

Comment: i think only way to do is manually code test for all subclasses of base class, but thanks to polymorphism u need only one test method for them all.

Answer (score 1):

All the method that didn't changed in you sub-classes are checked in the test of your abstract class.
The method that was not changed don't need to be tested again under the scope of the extending classes.

If some method was override it will be a vary bad decision to apply the same tests on them as they might have different business logic. Hence if someone inherit your class he should write his own tests for the methods that he had overridden.

This is all the point of inheritance to change or add logic business logic.

Comment: The issue I'm trying to solve is that the person extending the class, might not know all the ways it can break.  If they override the class and see that a test fails, they can either override the test, or fix the method to not fail the test.  Otherwise, they don't even know that their code is breaking.

Answer (score 1):

So I thought about some workaround I dont know if you will like it but lets try.

My solution is to make test that find all implementation of your Abstract class 
Instantiate all the concert classes And then it will run the same tests on all of them.

You will need the following API for getting all subclass by reflection

```
 <dependency>
         <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
         <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
         <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
 </dependency>
```

and then use it like this

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("packageName");
Set<Class<? extends YourClass>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(YourClass.class);
```

And then Instantiate  and run

To run each test with different implemention you will need @RunWith(Parameterized.class)

this is a link on how to do Parameterized test in Junit

[Easy way of running the same junit test over and over?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492856/easy-way-of-running-the-same-junit-test-over-and-over)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a simple way to do it automatically.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492184/how-do-you-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-java) on trying to get all subclasses of a given class for more details on why.