# Is possible to run same test multiple times with Maven Surefire Plugin?

Tags: java, maven-3, junit4, maven-plugin, surefire

There is a config value [rerunFailingTestsCount](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#rerunFailingTestsCount) but I want to run a test method a configurable number of times even it is successful. Are there any options?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it is possible to configure `maven-surefire-plugin` to rerun passing tests.

However, you can configure the invocation count of a single test using the TestNG (not JUnit) [`@Test`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html) annotation:

```
@Test(invocationCount = 5)
public void testSomething() {
}
```

This will result in the `testSomething` method being tested 5 times.

If you don't want to go the TestNG route, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1493121/1743880) for a solution with JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have it configurable by implementing the IInvokedMethodListener beforeInvocation method, something to the effect :

```
method.getTestMethod().setInvocationCount(Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("configurablecount")));
```

System.getProperty can be replaced by however you want to configure it.  You can also probably control which tests to set the invocation count to change by passing testnames.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by duplicating the execution phases in `pom.xml`. The downsides are -- obviously -- it gets repetitive and tedious as the number of runs increases. One can also be more selective of a subset of tests to rerun in the "repetition" phases.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>phase-1</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <!-- Phase 1 configuration -->
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>phase-2</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <!-- Phase 2 configuration -->
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```