# run a testng file multiple times from maven

Tags: maven, loops, batch-file, testng

I'm searching how to run my testng file in a loop for example each hour with a batch file

To run my test I use this

```
mvn clean test
```

and it's working fine (I have the maven surefire plugin inside my pom)

I also tried to make an infinite loop in batch like this

```
:while
if %var% equ %var% (
   timeout /t %time_to_wait%
   goto :while
)
```

and this also works fine

but for some reason if I'm doing the 2 at the same times like this

```
:while
if %var% equ %var% (
   mvn clean test
   timeout /t %time_to_wait%
   goto :while
)
```

It will run my test, wait for the x seconds then instead of going back inside the loop it just stops

Any idea ?

Comment: before going into possible solutions, why do you need to run the same tests so many times?

Comment: Also, did you already check software solution, like the `@Repeat` annotation described in [this Stack Overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492856/easy-way-of-running-the-same-junit-test-over-and-over)?

Comment: What is `if %var% equ %var%` for? why not simply omit it? and what did you set `var` to? it will fail of `var` is empty! and what is `mvn`? is it a batch file on its own? if so, precede it with `call `...

Comment: @aschipfl yes, it's a batch on its own, but I still have doubts about the whole approach, the idea behind, and the context (continuous integration?)

Comment: The goal is to run a battery of tests on multiple device each day for example to verify that the app is running the way it should
mvn is the cmd to run maven tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you need some continuous integration.

Have you already try [jenkins](https://jenkins.io) or any other servers ?

Comment: I'm giving a look at it right now it seems to be what I need.