# Easy way to run JUnit testcase over and over with @Before and @After method for every run

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, test-suite

The question here is a variant of [Easy way of running the same junit test over and over?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492856/easy-way-of-running-the-same-junit-test-over-and-over)

The above mentioned link nicely answered how to run a test repetitively through IntelliJ.

However, I need a way to run the entire test suite multiple times, with @Before and @After for every run.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use junit Rule for this purposes

Here is link with example:

https://www.testwithspring.com/lesson/introduction-to-junit-4-rules/

Here is documentation link :

https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Rule.html