# How to run a junit test multiple times using gradle command line

Tags: java, gradle

Idea here is to run same test 10 times in CI job to make sure the test is not flaky. If one of the iteration fails then we will mark the CI job as failed and the reason for failure will be taken care.

Comment: If it is a specific test case, why not go for this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1493121/1531124

Comment: I want to apply this approach for all newly added/modified test cases, so without changing the base test code is there any property we can pass through gradle command line to run multiple times? @GhostCat

Comment: No idea here. The first problem might be: gradle is very eager to only do work ... when something has changed. So even just calling `gradle tests` again won't achieve much, you would have to at least do a clean first.